# How to change user permission in October CMS

Tags: octobercms

How am I get the user permission to manage media.
Some user can privilege for download only and other users have more privileges than particular user. how can I manage this scenario by using October CMS.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

So I take it you want media manager in read-only mode? I'm not sure such a permission exists at the moment, you should submit an issue for it on the [October GitHub](http://github.com/octobercms/october/issues) to have a permission created.

Answer (score 1):

You can change permission by assign perticular user group in October CMS.

1) Open Settings > Administrators.

2) Click on Add new Administrators. In New Administrators form you can see Group field. In that you can select any group with perticular permission.
[image: Add New User]

Note : you can create new group with new permission criteria.